# mthaml Illegal nesting: nesting within echo is illegal

Tags: php, haml

I need to execute the following haml

```
  = form_open('login', array('method' => 'POST'))
    %p
      %label{:for => "password"} Password
      = form_input($login_password)
    %p
      %input{:name => "submit", :type => "submit", :value => "Login"}
  = form_close()
```

But I keep getting

```
with message 'Illegal nesting: nesting within echo is illegal in
```

I understand the error and that it's nested but how do i fix it? It worked fine with the other php library called phamlp

Comment: The error message states it all? Call a break with an echo outside your nested function?

Comment: Thanks! How do I do this? That's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: I think I found a way using both !=  form_open  and %p>  is this the right way?

Comment: If it works then who cares? It works

Comment: I care, I don't want to hack things up I want to make sure I'm doing it the right way if I'm going to be using this across dozens pages.